# Battle Cry feat daily uses and items providing a bonus to Charisma

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I was wondering if bonuses to stats could affect the number of uses of certain abilities, specifically, do you get more uses of the Battle Cry feat if you got a Ioun Stone giving you +2 to Charisma?

If so, which uses get consumed first, the ones given by the bonus? What happens if after using Battle Cry, the Ioun Stone gets destroyed, making you lose the bonus?

Answer (score 4):

It depends whether or not the bonus is temporary or permanent:

> Temporary increases to your Charisma score give you a bonus on Charisma-based skill checks. This bonus also applies to any spell DCs based on Charisma and the DC to resist your channeled energy.

<sup>([Ability Scores → Bonuses → Temporary Bonuses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/BASICS-ABILITY-SCORES/ability-scores/#Temporary_Bonuses))</sup>

Since “uses of the Battle Cry feat” isn’t listed here, a temporary bonus to Charisma doesn’t help.

But!

> #### Permanent Bonuses
>
> Ability bonuses with a duration greater than 1 day actually increase the relevant ability score after 24 hours. Modify all skills and statistics related to that ability. This might cause you to gain skill points, hit points, and other bonuses. These bonuses should be noted separately in case they are removed.

<sup>([Ability Scores → Bonuses → Permanent Bonuses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/#Permanent_Bonuses))</sup>

Uses of Battle Cry would go under the heading of “all statistics related to that ability,” so a permanent bonus to Charisma does increase your daily uses of Battle Cry. And since *ioun stones* stick around permanently, that would be a permanent bonus, so yes, you could use Battle Cry more as long as you have that.

> If so, which uses get consumed first, the ones given by the bonus? What happens if after using Battle Cry, the Ioun Stone gets destroyed, making you lose the bonus?

This is a really good question that the rules do not answer. You’ll have to ask your GM how they want to handle it for their game. It kind of just comes down to whether you see these things having a specific number of “uses” that get consumed, as spell slots do—that would imply that you could use the use from the bonus first—or if you see the use limit as just a maximum and you count how many times you’ve used the ability until you hit that cap—that would imply that you have to obey your cap, whatever it is, at all times, so if the cap is lowered then you just miss out.

You’ll have to ask your GM which way they see things.